# How to get the checksum of a binary file in ML DB

Tags: xquery, marklogic

The objective is to detect whether a binary file has been changed / modified.
If there is a "real" change, a certain process will be triggered.

The binary files like pdf or zip have been stored inside ML.
I am thinking to generate the checksum like `xdmp:md5` for xml node for those binary files as well.
However `xdmp:md5` works for string only. How to do that with binary uri stored inside ML DB?

OR should I simply use external tool to generate the checksum and store that file signature as a **property** for that binary file?

Comment: I believe xdmp:md5 also works with binary-node similar to xdmp:sha functions @Mads Hansen mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to use the `document-node()` instead of the `binary()`, the error message is a bit misleading:

> arg1 is not of type xs:string

It should probably state: "*arg1 is not of type xs:string or binary()*"

The xdmp:md5 and xdmp:sha* hash functions accept an `item()` that is either an `xs:string` or a `binary()`

> $data Data to be hashed. Must be xs:string or a binary node.

So look to use either of them:

- [xdmp:md5()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:md5)
- [xdmp:sha512()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sha512)
- [xdmp:sha384()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sha384)
- [xdmp:sha256()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sha256)
- [xdmp:sha1()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sha1)

Just note that you need to send the `binary()` node, not the `document-node()`. So, if you select the document with `fn:doc()`, XPath to the node:

```
doc("/myDoc.pdf")/binary() => xdmp:md5()
```